# Chart.js how to change width of color

Tags: chart.js

Hi guys I am using chart js 2.9.3 so that i have problem with color
[image]

how can i change width of color selected in red circle because i have a lot of data so i need decrease width of rectangle's
i want decrease rectangle's width twice
i searched it before asking but i could not find anything that can help me
there are my code

```
var infosum = {
            label: chart[i].data_name+' ['+chart[i].data_id + ']',
            data: chart[i].sum,
            backgroundColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0)',
            borderColor: '#'+(Math.random() * 0xFFFFFF << 0).toString(16).padStart(6, '0'),
            borderWidth: 2
        };

if ($('#linearChart'+type).length) {
              var ctx = document.getElementById('linearChart'+type);
              var linearChartjs = new Chart(ctx, {
                type: 'line',
                data: {
                  labels: monthyear,
                  datasets: data,
                },
                options: {
                  responsive: true,
                  scales: {
                    yAxes: [{
                      ticks: {
                        beginAtZero: true
                      }
                    }]
                  }
                }
              });
            }
         }
```

thanks guys beforehand

Answer (score 2):

This can be done through the [`legend.labels.boxWidth`](https://www.chartjs.org/docs/latest/configuration/legend.html#legend-label-configuration) option as follows:

```
options: {
  responsive: true,
  legend: {
    labels: {
      boxWidth: 15
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

> `boxWidth`: Width of coloured box (default value is `40`).

Comment: sorry but it is not working and also there is no error